# jQuery - Reload head scripts after a jQuery.get function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, import, get

I´ve written this code to switch my html content:

```
$.get( "header.html", function( data ) {
  $( "#header-import" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
$.get( "navigation.html", function( data ) {
  $( "#navigation-import" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
$.get( "home.html", function( data ) {
  $( "#content-import" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

It seems like that my imported JS scripts aren't loading correctly.
I think I have to "reload" the  section in my main html file after the pages loaded. Any Ideas guys? I tried some stuff but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .ajax() and having a dataType, produces a perfect working end result:

```
<html>
    <head>

    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){


            jQuery.ajax({
                url : "test1.html",
                dataType: "html",
                success : function (data) {
                    jQuery( "#header" ).html( data );
                    console.log("a: "+data);
                    //alert( "Load was performed." );
                }
            });

            jQuery.ajax({
                url : "test2.html",
                dataType: "html",
                success : function (data) {
                    jQuery( "#navigation" ).html( data );
                    console.log("b: "+data);
                    //alert( "Load was performed." );
                }
            });



        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <div id="header">

        </div>

        <div id="navigation">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worken fine, thank you, do u know how I can call the function onclick?

Comment: Awesome! Yes... you would encapsulate both `jQuery.ajax()` calls in: `jQuery("SELECTOR").on( 'click', function () {  //jQuery.ajax() calls });` where `SELECTOR` is either a class or an ID (if it is a class, it would be `.classname` if it is ID, it would be `#ID`

Comment: Worked perfectly, do u know how I can add stuff in the head when something is loading: f.ex.:
          $.ajax({
              url : "home.html",
              dataType: "html",
              success : function (data) {
                  jQuery( "#content-import" ).html( data );
              }});
With this it should import: "<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>" in the <head> section.

Comment: Glad to hear; as to your follow-up question: why not just include that lib in the `<head>` to begin with? if it is part of **ONLY** one file, then include the lib in that file's `<head>`